# Why is my scope lost in $http function on angularjs and d3js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to draw a barchart with dynamically loaded data with angularjs and d3js. 
When I call

`$http.get('groups/all_groups.json').then($scope.groups = [10,20,30,40,60, 80, 20, 50]);`

it works and I can plot the data in my directive, but when I try

`$http.get('groups/all_groups.json').then(function (response) {
                $scope.groups = [10,20,30,40,60, 80, 20, 50];} // eventually, here is dynamic data`

then I get an error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at bind (http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js:3727:45)
    at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.data (http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js:3801:9)
    at directiveDefinitionObject.link

I believe d3js scope within that directive is not set but how can I "export" the http-response to d3js?

Edit: 
Here is the directive:

```
.directive('barsChart', function ($parse) {
    //explicitly creating a directive definition variable
    //this may look verbose but is good for clarification purposes
    //in real life you'd want to simply return the object {...}
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        //We restrict its use to an element
        //as usually  <bars-chart> is semantically
        //more understandable
        restrict: 'E',
        //this is important,
        //we don't want to overwrite our directive declaration
        //in the HTML mark-up
        replace: false,

        //our data source would be an array
        //passed thru chart-data attribute
        scope: {data: '=chartData'},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //in D3, any selection[0] contains the group
            //selection[0][0] is the DOM node
            //but we won't need that this time
            var chart = d3.select(element[0]);
            //to our original directive markup bars-chart
            //we add a div with out chart stling and bind each
            //data entry to the chart
            chart.append("div").attr("class", "chart")
                .selectAll('div')
                .data(scope.data).enter().append("div")
                .transition().ease("elastic")
                .style("width", function (d) {
                    return d + "%";
                })
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d + "%";
                });
            //a little of magic: setting it's width based
            //on the data value (d)
            //and text all with a smooth transition
        }
    };
    return directiveDefinitionObject;
```

The html element:

```
<bars-chart chart-data="groups"></bars-chart>
```

and the controller:

```
    .controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
       $http.get('groups/all_groups.json').then(function (response) {
            $scope.groups = [10,20,30,40,60, 80, 20, 50];
            console.log($scope.groups);
       }, function(response){
           console.log('error');
       });
    }])
```

Comment: You're not showing us enough code.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript language, all var (expect global var) are define inside a block function. In your code, you lost your context in `then(function (response) {`. In this function $scope does not exist anymore. You have keep a ref to `this` to bring your old context in this function. Like this :

```
 .controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
       var vm = this;
       $http.get('groups/all_groups.json').then(function (response) {
            vm.$scope.groups = [10,20,30,40,60, 80, 20, 50];
            console.log(vm.$scope.groups);
       }, function(response){
           console.log('error');
       });
    }])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change much. I believe that the binding between chartData and groups is not correct. When the http-response-function gets called and receives its data, the view does not notice it. Any ideas on how to have groups and chartData in sync?

Answer (score 0):

With $http.get you can also pass a config object :

I put the scope in there like this:

var config = {
method: 'GET',
scp: $scope
}

than at the success callaback I recovered:
var scp = response.config.scp;

I have a similar problem and I solved this way ... I believe that is a dirty trick. But I don't know how to solve this either.